# How go to end loop shortcut in OllyDbg?

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

[image]

The loop starts with (`ˇ`) sign.  I want to go to the loop's end (`^`).  But I don't know a shortcut to do so.

Comment: Put cursor on instruction and say "run to cursor".

Comment: @TruthSerum I think it's about jumping (in the CPU view, not with the IP) to the other "end" of the loop/jump brace, not executing until reaching a certain known location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple: **Press Enter** or right-click and choose "Follow". OllyDbg will then follow the address in the CPU window.

This also works with `call`s, references in `mov`s or `dd`s, etc., basically everywhere where the brace shows up on the left side.

Comment: By the way you can press minus (in OllyDbg: Numpad minus) to go back to the previous location you were on, and plus to go back from going back (i.e. forward). So I often peek into functions that would get called or branches that would be jumped to by pressing Enter, checking what the function/branch does, and then minus to get back.